# Why are 2 `alert` messages when 1 is expected?

Tags: angularjs

Below is the HTML

```
<div ng-app = 'myApp'> 
    <div class='some'>
    </div> 
</div>
```

The angular code is below: -

```
<script>
    var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);

    myApp.directive('some', function() {

    alert('hi');


    return {
            restrict: 'C',
            link: linkFN,
        }
});

</script>
```

this is the [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sangramfuture/Q7rz5/1/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you included AngularJS twice: the first time is in the external resources, and the second one is in `Frameworks & Extensions` list. Remove any of them.